# Using template of pushpin, created in XAML, in code

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I created a template for pushpin (image and some text) by XAML. However i don't know how to use it in my C# code.

Here is my temlate:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="myMap" Width="446" Loaded="myMap_Loaded">
                    <maps:Map.Layers>
                        <maps:MapLayer>
                            <maps:MapOverlay>
                                <toolkit:Pushpin x:Name="myPushpin">
                                    <toolkit:Pushpin.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:Pushpin">
                                            <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Image x:Name="pushpinImg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="30"/>
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="pushpinText" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Green" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>                                                
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </toolkit:Pushpin.Template>
                                </toolkit:Pushpin>                                    
                            </maps:MapOverlay>
                        </maps:MapLayer>
                    </maps:Map.Layers>
                </maps:Map>
```

Comment: You need to research "DataTemplate" and how to use it in XAML. What you will do is turn your pushpin into a datatemplate. Then assign that datatemplate to your ItemsTemplate for your map. Here is an example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620947.aspx

Comment: Can you give me an example of assigning to ItemsTemplate?

Comment: Look at the link I provided. You will see "ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LogoTemplate}">" this is the Binding you need